# Calculate distance from coordinates PHP Function

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using MySQLi with mysqlnd driver, and using a function to get long/lat coordinates and calculate the distance between them, however I'm having issues with strange numbers and errors regarding "expected double, string given".

In my database, the long/lat values are stored as "Decimal (18,15)". I then use a MySQLi query to retireve this from the database, and store them in a PHP Variable like so:

```
$latitudeTo = $postcoderow[latitude];
$float_latitudeTo = floatval($latitudeTo);
$longitudeTo = $postcoderow[longitude];
$float_longitudeTo = floatval($longitudeTo);
```

The other set of long/lat are the same (just using different names).

However, the postcodes will be only from the UK, and using the following PHP Function

```
function calculateDistance($float_latitudeFrom, $float_longitudeFrom, $float_latitudeTo, $float_longitudeTo, $earthMeanRadius = 3440) {
$deltaLatitude = deg2rad($float_latitudeTo - $float_latitudeFrom);
$deltaLongitude = deg2rad($float_longitudeTo - $float_longitudeFrom);
$a = sin($deltaLatitude / 2) * sin($deltaLatitude / 2) +
     cos(deg2rad($float_latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad(float_latitudeTo)) *
     sin($deltaLongitude / 2) * sin($deltaLongitude / 2);
$c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
return $earthMeanRadius * $c;
}

//Function call with the coordinates.
$miles = calculateDistance($float_latitudeFrom, $float_longitudeFrom, $float_latitudeTo, $float_longitudeTo, $earthMeanRadius = 3440);
```

I'm getting values of 3000+ miles returned (I just echo '.$miles.')

How do I store $float_latitudeTo... etc as doubles, as they are decimals from the database, however are converted to a string which is causing errors. I think the PHP Function itself is fine, just how I'm parsing the values.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which line is giving the error? Could you copy/paste the exact error?

Comment: Hello, of course: Warning: deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /var/www/html/searchmaster.php on line 40 // cos(deg2rad($float_latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad(float_latitudeTo)) *

Comment: Where are you setting `$float_latitudeFrom`'s value?

Comment: I see that you're using `floatval()` to convert the strings to floats but can you try typecasting `$float_latitudeFrom` inside `deg2rad()` and see if the function accepts the value? i.e. `deg2rad((float)$float_latitudeFrom);`

Comment: @PublicDisplayName Did you try type casting the variables to float?

Comment: I tried typecasting like you said, using "$a = sin($deltaLatitude / 2) * sin($deltaLatitude / 2) +
         cos(deg2rad((float)$float_latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad((float)$float_latitudeTo)) * 
         sin($deltaLongitude / 2) * sin($deltaLongitude / 2);"  and the errors do appear to have dissapeared. However I'm still getting a value of "3058.9101929426" which suggests there is still a string in the query from somewhere

Comment: Inside `sin()` you're dividing a float by an int (2) and this will give you an int result, change 2 to 2.00 and it should work, I believe. @PublicDisplayName

Comment: your function is not optimized but correct. Your conversions too, so, to me, this only leaves data as the possible culprit. Just echo what comes from the db.

Comment: You should be using [proper types for geographic data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-datatypes.html), then you could just have MySQL [do the math for you](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)!